# Working with "~" in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a data set that has names that contain `~` within them. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to filter or incorporate these cells in a formula.

For example, I tried to use a text cell that had `~` within the name, but I would receive a `#N/A error`. I know that my VLOOKUP formula works because the only errors I receive are with cells that contain `~` within them.

I even attempted to filter out these results, but excel would replace the filter and treat it like a wildcard filter.

My questions are:
 - How do I filter `~`?
 - How do I use text cells that contain `~` in VLOOKUPS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using double tildes:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"~","~~"),A:B,2,false)
```

The tilde is the special character in Excel to escape other special characters. Use a tilde to make the tilde you want to match a literal tilde (e.g. `*` in excel find matches any number of characters, but `~*` will match a literal `*`).

The data I used it on is:

```
   A       B        C           D
~Hello     1      ~Hello       =VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"~","~~"),A:B,2,false)
Hello      2
```

Cell D1 is returning me `1` (meaning it is matching `~Hello`).

Comment: +1 Jerry - The range in VLOOKUP should presumably be A:B.....

Comment: @barryhoudini oops, right. The data I was testing was actually another one ^^;

Comment: @pnuts Yes, it is, but it won't work for `~Hello~`, right.

Comment: @wastold2get1 You're welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

Clever Answer Jerry.
Here is Further Explaination,

Microsoft Excel uses the tilde (~) as a marker to indicate that the next character is a literal. When you use the Find and Replace dialog box to find or replace a character such as a tilde (~), an asterisk (*), or a question mark (?), you must add a tilde (~) before the character in the Find what box.

[How to find and replace tildes and wildcard characters in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214138)