# Using a ~ tilde in a Vlookup excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

How would I use a Vlookup with multiple tildes in the text string? It would look something like this:

SWBC ~ 7797_Dodge_Challenger ~ Video ~ New

What would the VLookup formula be?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please provide more context. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Originally I tried this formula that I found on here but it didn't work because the text doesn't start with ~
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(C1,"~","~~"),A:B,2,false)

Comment: That formula applies to all tilde characters in the lookup value - it doesn't matter where they are in the text. You may have to provide more information if it's not working for you

Comment: @SOAnalytics, please don't provide context in a comment. Edit your post and add the context. In addition to the formula you tried, please also provide sample data and tell us what your expected results are.

Answer (score 0):

With a table like this where the value you want to search for (`D3`) has tilde characters, you can use `=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(D3,"~","~~"),A:B,2,FALSE)` to force excel to search for literal `~` characters:

[image]

The output from the vlookup formula is `orange`

See [Working with "~" in excel](https://superuser.com/questions/603266/working-with-in-excel) for more information

Comment: The new XLOOKUP deals with characters literally by default: `=XLOOKUP(D3,A:A,B:B)`